# Multiple JQuery filtering criteria (www.lynda.com)

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to find a JQuery filtering system like the one used in www.lynda.com [click here to see](http://www.lynda.com/Video-training-tutorials/78-0.html). Can anyone please send me a link where can I find the plugin or if there is any available tutorial for it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is one, so far I've found:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-jquery-to-manipulate-and-filter-data/

**EDIT:**
You could also you some modified version of this: http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/javascript/how-to-build-a-fast-simple-list-filter-with-jquery/

**EDIT:**
Also found this, author site is down so I was unable to be sure but I think it does what you want: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/magictags

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of Googling, I'd personally use [TableSorter](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://tablesorter.ru/docs/) (it's in Russian, but I linked to a Google Translate version). It allows you to specify *what* sorts the elements upon sorting (value, length of text, custom extracted text, etc.), which is really useful.

But it would be a better learning experience if you were to write one from scratch. If it's good enough, you can even distribute it to others!